# Creating Sub workflows using GoJs

Tags: gojs

Using GoJs evaluation version, is it possible to create a sub workflow and render the logical path. If yes, please guide me how to do so on this [example](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html) flowchart

Comment: Please post what did you already tried.

Comment: Actually, I have not tried on the GoJs. I am a newbie and I have made some basic flowcharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sub workflows, you have a number of choices, but it is most common to use **Group**s: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/groups.html and https://gojs.net/latest/intro/subgraphs.html.

I'm not sure what you mean by "render the logical path", but perhaps you want to highlight some links.  If so, this sample demonstrates what you are looking for: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/distances.html.